# How can I Automate a CSS Build Process?

Tags: css, build-process

On larger projects I have segmented stylesheets that have rules written for specific modules. I'd like to be able to automate a process that minifies my CSS (at least remove commenting) and also combine multiple CSS files into a single asset to minimize requests.

Comment: What type of server/server technology? Linux/PHP, etc

Comment: I'm using ruby and rails for most of my projects but some are also in Python. My production servers run ubuntu and my dev machine is a mac running 10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5+ I would highly recommend [Scaffold](http://wiki.github.com/anthonyshort/csscaffold/).  It blew my mind when I saw how easy it was - yet how powerful.  [Watch the video](http://vimeo.com/6175674) to see it in action

Supports:

- Constants
- Mixins
- Nested Selectors
- Expressions
- Caching and gzipping
- Extendable through plugins

Thus you can do things like:

```
/*include/aggregate other CSS files*/
@include '/css/reset.css';
@include '/css/sections/layout.css';
#foo{
  background-color:#efefef;
  color:#333;
  /* nested selectors will expand in the output */
  a{
    color:#11f;
    padding:2px;
  }
}
```

and have the whole thing **minified**, **gzipped** and **cached** as a *single* CSS file

Comment: Interesting I personally am using ruby so I wonder if there is anything like this in other languages. I know Rails does all of these things except minify. Maybe I'll have to extend it myself.